# Topological Sort Graph - find all vertices with no successors

Tags: java, topological-sort

I am doing a project in which I am finding a logical course sequence based on prerequisites using a topological sort.  Here is my sort method:

```
public void topo()  //topological sort
{
    int orig_nVerts = nVerts;  //remember how many verts

    while(nVerts > 0)
    {
        int currentVertex = noSuccessors();


        if(currentVertex == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Graph has cycles");
            return;
        }

        sortedDepArray[nVerts - 1] = vertexList[currentVertex].department;
        sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 1] = vertexList[currentVertex].courseNum;
        deleteVertex(currentVertex);        
    } //end while
    System.out.println("Topologically sorted order: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < orig_nVerts; j++)
        System.out.print(sortedDepArray[j] + sortedCrsNumArray[j] + " ");

}//end topo()
```

What I need to be able to do is find all of the vertices in a particular pass of the sort that don't have any successors, and sort them by course number (each vertex contains a department and course number, such as CS140).  Here is the actual description:

> During the topological sort, when selecting a node with no successors:
>   first, find all such vertices,
>   then, select courses based upon the course number(integer part) that would tend to have a student take lower-level courses first.  That is, if the candidates happened to me: M152, M131, and CS140 you should select M152 to make it appear later.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
This is what I have tried so far:

```
while(nVerts > 0)
    {
        int currentVertex = noSuccessors();

        if(currentVertex == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Graph has cycles");
            return;
        }

        Vertex currVert = vertexList[currentVertex];
        int currCourseNum = currVert.courseNum;
        if(sortedCrsNumArray.length != 0)
        {
            if(currCourseNum > sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 1])
            {
                sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 2] = sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 1];
                sortedDepArray[nVerts - 2] = sortedDepArray[nVerts - 1];
            }
        }

        sortedDepArray[nVerts - 1] = vertexList[currentVertex].department;
        sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 1] = vertexList[currentVertex].courseNum;
        deleteVertex(currentVertex);

    } //end while
```

But I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at:
 `sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 2] = sortedCrsNumArray[nVerts - 1];`.

Comment: Well you can only execute that code if nVerts >= 2.

Comment: nVerts is 24.  I just didn't show that code.

Comment: The sortedDepArray and sortedCrsNumArray also both have sizes of 24.